# Answering "Do your parents both have valid visas?" when only one has

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, children

My son is 4 years old, and while I am filling out questions on the new CGI Portal (for applying B2 visa to the USA), I came across a question:

> Do your parents both have valid visas?

In our case, one of the parents has a valid USA visa, while the other doesn't. Is the portal asking if either of the parents has a valid visa, or must both of them have one?

Comment: Are both parents planning to travel to the US with the 4 year old, or just the parent with the valid visa?

Comment: Read the question as it is written.

Comment: The question "do your parents both have valid visas" does not imply that having a parent with a valid visa is required.  For example, a child who is traveling to the US without parents may be granted a visa even though neither parent has a valid visa.

Comment: @Traveller another possibility is that neither parent is going to travel to the US with the child.

Answer (score 17):

Don't try to reinterpret, second-guess, or read between the lines.
Just answer the question as it's written.

> Do your parents **both** have valid visas?

In your case "No" is clearly the correct answer.

Note that this is almost universally the correct way to answer any question on any visa application for any country or region.
Don't try to decipher what they might be trying to figure out by asking this question or what you think the answer might imply about you.
Just answer the question, as it's written, as simply and accurately as you can.